# I need help with baking

Tags: texture-baking, baking

since i'm beginer i've been following tutorials of blender guru. Right now i'm on the Anvil series and i got badly stuck.

[image]

[image]

This is the first thing that happened to me after the baking. So i was trying to flip normals. That didn't do anything. For the baking i had 2 anvils, one for sculpting and first as original low poly. So i applied subdivision on low poly anvil as well and then tried again. But then i got this.

[image]

I'm lost, i'll be still googling but if if anyone knows, please help me.

Thank you in advance.

**Tutorial video:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0r-cGjVKvGw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should've specified what issue "this" refers to.
Anyway, assuming your issue is that you're seeing polygon edges in your normal map, your mistake was not changing the shading from flat to smooth on at least one of the two models.

Set both models' (low and high-poly) shading mode to smooth and then bake again.
Those awful edges should disappear from your normal map altogether.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. Yes, my issue was seeing those awful edges. The smoothing helped, thank you a lot.

Comment: If the answer solved your issue, please learn [how to accept it](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) @Eporomis